# NG-Repeat compare to current date using filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok I have an object that contains a list of dates and I'm traversing it like so:

```
<select ng-click="monthpicker()" >
<option class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)"      value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date  | date:'yyyy-MMM' }}</option> 
</select>
```

using ng-repeat this returns the following:

```
<select ng-click="monthpicker()">
  <!-- ngRepeat: returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump) -->
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
  <option class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(alldatesdump)" value="2013-Nov">2013-Nov</option>
```

and so on for each month in the object now this is because it's returning a month name and a  year for each day in the object. 
Ok so i have two questions: 
1: How do i filter the results so they only return one example of each month name and the year? 
2: how do i set it so it returns only from the current month? 
I'd like to achive this using AngularJS filters only but i do have jquery avail if needed!
*******************UPDATE***************************
heres the current scope item in my JS file:

```
scope.monthpicker = function(alldatesdump){

var alldatesdump = booking.getalldates();
/*for (var date in alldatesdump){
    if (alldatesdump.hasOwnProperty(date)){
        console.log(date);
    }
}
for (var date in alldatesdump) {
   var obj = alldatesdump[date];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      // important check that this is objects own property 
      // not from prototype prop inherited
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
      }
   }
}*/
return alldatesdump;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of how I used a filter to only show orders from the last two days

```
.filter('getOrders', function() {
  return function (orders) {

    var filtered_list = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {

      var two_days_ago = new Date().getTime() - 2*24*60*60*1000;
      var last_modified = new Date(orders[i].last_modified).getTime();

      if (two_days_ago <= last_modified) {
        filtered_list.push(orders[i]);
      }
    }
    return filtered_list;
  }
});
```

DOM looks like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders|getOrders">
```

Hopefully this fiddle helps [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/kMksx/)

Comment: Thank you that looks very helpfull, what does your dom binding look like if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @vimes1984 I added it to the answer. The "orders" in the return function is the same as the orders| being filtered.

Comment: good answer. see also this, which is very similar, but allows you to set the period to look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642449/how-do-i-filter-angular-ng-repeat-to-use-ranges-of-dates/24642842?noredirect=1#comment38197216_24642842