# How do I filter angular ng-repeat to use ranges of dates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am using ng-repeat to list some information about an event, one of which is a date field. I would like to filter the dates, for example, be able to show events in the next 30 days. I am not sure what direction to take to accomplish this.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Start Time</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="eventData in eventListData  | orderBy:'+StartDateTime'">
  <td>{{eventData.Title}}</td>
  <td>{{eventData.Description}}</td>
  <td>{{eventData.StartDateTime|date:'d MMM yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the syntax for orderBy is wrong. It should be "orderBy:'+StartDateTime'" where +/- controls asc/desc direction, and 'StartDateTime' (mind single-quotes) is the field to pluck from.

Use timestamps for StartDate & do > now - < now + 30days, and then you have 2 options:

- Filter model array before it gets to your view
- Make a filter for angular & use it

I like the second option better, and I feel like it better fits  with the spirit of angular, and allows more dynamic messing with the data. I made an example [here](http://codepen.io/konsumer/pen/elrkg?editors=101)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// filter array by @field {String}
// return items from today to @days {Number} from now
// eg: events | upComing:'StartDateTime':30
app.filter('upComing', function(){
  return function(items, field, days){
    var timeStart = Date.now();
    var timeEnd = Date.now() + (days * 86400000); // 1 day in ms
    return items.filter(function(item){
      return (item[field] > timeStart && item[field] < timeEnd);
    });
  };
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  // demo data, StartDateTime should be numbers in your data
  $scope.eventListData = [
   {
     Title:'Event 1 (last in 30 dys)',
     Description:'A cool Event',
     StartDateTime: Date.now() + (86400000 * 5) // in 5 days
   },
   {
     Title:'Event 2 (next)',
     Description:'A cool Event',
     StartDateTime: Date.now() + 86400000 // in a day
   },
   {
     Title:'Event 3 (next next)',
     Description:'A cool Event',
     StartDateTime: Date.now() + (86400000 * 2) // in 2 days
   },
   {
     Title:'Too-far-away Event',
     Description:'A cool Event',
     StartDateTime: Date.now() + (86400000 * 40) //  in 40 days
   },
   {
     Title:'Already-happend Event',
     Description:'A cool Event',
     StartDateTime: Date.now() - (86400000 * 2) //  2 days ago
   }
  ];
});
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Angular Date Filter</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Start Time</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="eventData in eventListData  | upComing:'StartDateTime':30 | orderBy:'+StartDateTime'">
  <td>{{eventData.Title}}</td>
  <td>{{eventData.Description}}</td>
  <td>{{eventData.StartDateTime|date:'d MMM yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax corrections, which I will fix in my example then I am off to try your solution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: no prob. the codepen should show better how to actually use the filter.

Comment: @konsumer A lot of event finding sites have "in next 7 days" and "in next 30 days"  How does one put buttons like those in the view so that it can communicate with your awesome filter?  ie. I'd like to allow a user to change the days variable.

Comment: @kyle-pennell: Use variables instead of strings for upComing & orderBy, then ng-click handler to set them. Something like this: http://codepen.io/konsumer/pen/clyaH