# Filter by data from current date/time angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter this json so it only shows entries from the current time onwards:

JSON
http://www.football-data.org/teams/354/fixtures/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures.fixtures | greaterThan:fixture.date:date">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{teamName(fixture.awayTeam)}}</td>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    .controller('fixturesController', function($scope, $routeParams, footballdataAPIservice) {
        $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
        $scope.fixtures = [];
        $scope.date = new Date();

        footballdataAPIservice.getFixtures($scope.id).success(function (response) {
            $scope.fixtures = response; 
        }); 


});
```

FILTER

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp', [])

    .filter('greaterThan', function() {
            return function (actualDate, comparisonDate) {
                return Date(actualDate) > Date(comparisonDate);
            };
        });
```

this isn't working for me, anyone see why not?

Answer (score 0):

You're problem seems to be on the date comparison.

Try to change it to:

```
 return actualDate > new Date(comparisonDate);
```

because `actualDate` is a js Date object whereas `comparisonDate` is just a string from json.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return the date that is greater, not whether or not actual date is larger than comparison date. Am I correct?

At any rate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335409/ng-repeat-compare-to-current-date-using-filter) is an issue similar to yours. Working with date time objects solves your comparison issue.

Comment: yes, the entries with dates that are later than current date